# Unable to pipe infinite output of console app using PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, pipe, stdout, stdin

During development of a console app I noticed that I'm unable to pipe its output into itself in PowerShell.

I created a small repro (source below) that works like this:

```
PS> .\but-why.exe print # continuously prints a random number every 500 ms
1746112985
1700785785
331650882
...
```

```
PS> .\but-why.exe read # echoes stdin
foo                    # this was typed
read 'foo'
bar                    # this too
read 'bar'
```

```
PS> "foo","bar" | .\but-why.exe read
read 'foo'
read 'bar'
```

But when I try to feed the output of `print` into `read` nothing happens:

```
PS> .\but-why.exe print | .\but-why.exe read
```

Same when I redirect all outputs to the success stream:

```
PS> .\but-why.exe print *>&1 | .\but-why.exe read
```

However, when I use CMD everything works as expected:

```
CMD> but-why.exe print | but-why.exe read
read '317394436'
read '1828759797'
read '767777814'
...
```

Through debugging I found that the second instance `.\but-why.exe read` never seems to be started.

Maybe it's my rather old PS version?

```
PS> $host.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  610
```

Source of the console app (net5.0):

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

switch (args[0]) {
    case "print": Print(); break;
    case "read": Read(); break;
}

void Print() {
    var rng = new Random();
    while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine(rng.Next());
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

void Read() {
    string? text;
    while ((text = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
        Console.WriteLine($"read '{text}'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're seeing a *design limitation* in *Windows PowerShell*** that has since been fixed in the cross-platform [*PowerShell [Core] 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) edition:

**When Windows PowerShell pipes data *to an external program*** (which is then invariably *text*), **it unexpectedly does *not* exhibit the usual *streaming* behavior.**

That is, instead of passing the originating command's lines (stringified objects) on *as they're being produced*, Windows PowerShell tries to *collect them all in memory first*, before piping them to the external program.

In your case, **because the first program never stops producing output, the Windows PowerShell engine never stops waiting for *all* output to be collected** and therefore effectively *hangs* (until it eventually runs out of memory) - the target program is never even launched, because that only happens *after* collecting the output has finished.

---

**Workarounds**:

- If feasible, switch to [*PowerShell [Core] 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), where this limitation has been removed.
- In Windows PowerShell, invoke your pipeline via `cmd.exe`, which does exhibit the expected streaming behavior, as you've observed.

  ```
  # Workaround via cmd.exe
  cmd /c '.\but-why.exe print | .\but-why.exe read'
  ```